# How to get value from HTML textbox in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I simply want to have a textbox on my webpage, using the HTML form, and input tags, and be able to have the inputted value be used by the Javascript on the page. My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="firstq"> 
<form id="firstbox">
    Choice: <input id="firstinput" type="text" name="choice">
</form>
</div>
```

and the Javascript I'm trying to use looks like this:

```
var topMenuChoice = document.getElementById("firstinput");
    document.write(topMenuChoice);
}
```

However, all I see on the webpage, underneath the textbox, is "[object HTMLInputElement]". What do I do to get this to work right?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript get input text value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)

Answer (score 1):

here's an example with `change` event listener for firing a function when there's a change in `form`

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var topMenuChoice = document.getElementById("firstinput");
topMenuChoice.addEventListener('change',function(e){
div.innerHTML = e.target.value/***e.target.value is your input***/


var divInner = div.innerHTML;
setTimeout(function(){
 document.write(divInner);
},2000)

})
```

```html
<form id="firstbox">Choice:
  <input id="firstinput" type="text" name="choice" value=66>
</form>
<div>look here!!</div>
```

Comment: No, I want to print the text directly to the page, not to the console.

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction, now, how do I go about assigning the value to a variable? To be used in math problems

Comment: @ethanzh it depends where you want to show the input value; in my updated example I'm setting innerHTML property on another div but there are many ways you could display it ; using document.write will rewrite your markup (deleting what was there before)

Comment: as for your other question , I suggest you look into JS data types ;

Answer (score 0):

Check this !

```
document.write(document.forms['firstbox'].firstinput.value);
```

OR

```
var topMenuChoice = document.getElementById("firstinput");
    document.write(topMenuChoice.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

```js
var htmlInputElementObjet = document.getElementById("firstinput");
document.write(htmlInputElementObjet.value);
```

```html
<div id="firstq"> 
<form id="firstbox">
    Choice: <input id="firstinput" type="text" name="choice" value="initial value">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text typed in your input you need to use the `value` property of the element. You can also use another HTML tag to show the results (avoid using document.write):

**HTML**

```
<div id="firstq"> 
  <form id="firstbox">
    Choice: <input id="firstinput" type="text" name="choice">
  </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var topMenuChoice = document.getElementById("firstinput");
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = topMenuChoice.value;
```

You have to consider the **usage of an event** (click, keypress) to control the exactly moment to retrieve the input value.

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('firstinput').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) { //detect enter key pressed
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = this.value;
  }
});
```

Comment: If I want the usage of the event to be hitting the 'enter' key, how would I go about doing that? Also, the code you posted isn't working the way I thought it would.

Comment: I have copy and pasted the code from the codepen exactly onto my source code, but I'm not getting the same behavior from it. Weird.

Comment: Could you poste your code on a code pen to review it?

Comment: I couldn't get code pen to work, I hope this is sufficient: http://pastebin.com/7cBiZZP0

Comment: You are missing a '}' at line 48

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88589/discussion-between-ianaya89-and-ethanzh).

Answer (score -1):

use the `value` property

```
var topMenuChoice = document.getElementById("firstinput");
    document.write(topMenuChoice).value;
}
```

Comment: The "[object HTMLInputElement]" is gone, but now when I type something in and hit enter, all that happens is the text disappears, it isn't printed onto the page like it's supposed to.